# Has anyone any knowledge on how to implement Butterfly PUF onto FPGA board?

Tags: fpga

I have designed the basic unit of the Butterfly PUF. Any suggestion on how to implement it onto the FPGA board?

Comment: Re write the code in HDL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this article: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4349783_Extended_abstract_the_butterfly_PUF_protecting_IP_on_every_FPGA ?

They claim to have implemented a Butterfly PUF on Xilinx's Virtex5 FPGA, and provide some theoretical background. 
The catch is that you REALLY must try to make the critical paths as symmetrical as possible, so the resulting delay comes from the production process variations, and not design. It turns out it's not that easy on FPGA, and there are other publications that proves the Butterfly PUF to be "ill suited for the FPGA" - 
https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/629.pdf

Anyway, to maintain the control of the paths symmetry you must go deeper - explore the SLICE architecture of your FPGA (what type are you using btw?) surely they have some sort of latch / FF element.